# Finding volume under surface and above a region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I'm asked to find $\underset{U}{\int}(x+y)^2\, dA$ where U is a region bounded by the lines

x = -1, x = 1, y = -1

... and by the curves

x=$y^2$ , y=1+$x^2$

Plot: http://d.pr/WYSg

I started out by finding the volume above the box [-1,1] x [-1,2]

$$\underset{-1}{\overset{2}{\int}}\underset{-1}{\overset{1}{\int}}(x+y)^{2}dx\,dy=8$$

And then subtracted the volume above the "upper parabola" y=1+$x^2$:
$$\underset{-1}{\overset{1}{\int}}\underset{1+x^{2}}{\overset{2}{\int}}(x+y)^{2}dy\, dx=-\frac{132}{35}$$

As well as the "lower parabola" x=$y^2$:
$$\underset{-1}{\overset{1}{\int}}\underset{y^{2}}{\overset{1}{\int}}(x+y)^{2}dx\, dy=-\frac{88}{105}$$

So I get $$8-(-\frac{132}{35})-(-\frac{88}{105})=\frac{1324}{105}\approx12.6095$$

Which is all fine and well, except that I really don't know if I did this correctly. Does it make sense that volume should be negative? And what about 12.6095 being greater than 8?

Comment: The integral of a positive quantity must be positive.  You've definitely made a mistake in that part.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been somewhat more helpful if you had written out a bit more of your process.  I am getting for the first integral:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \ \int_{-1}^{2} \ x^2 + 2xy + y^2  \ \ dy \ dx \ = \  \int_{-1}^{1}  \ (2x^2 + 4x + \frac{8}{3} + x^2 - x + \frac{1}{3} ) \  dx  $$

$$= \int_{-1}^{1} \ (3x^2 + 3x + 3 ) \ dx \ = \ (x^3 + 3x)\ |_{-1}^{1} \ = \ 8 \ . $$

So I agree with you there. I removed all odd functions in $x$ in the last integration, since the interval is symmetrical about the y-axis.

The second integral is

$$\int_{-1}^{1}  \int^{2}_{1+x^2} \ x^2 + 2xy + y^2  \ \ dy \ dx \ = \  \int_{-1}^{1}   \ (x^2y + xy^2 + \frac{1}{3}y^3) \ |^2_{1+x^2}  \ dx $$

$$= \ \int_{-1}^{1}   \ (2x^2 + 4x + \frac{8}{3} - x^2 - x^4 - x - 2x^3 - x^5 - \frac{1}{3} - x^2 - x^4 - \frac{1}{3}x^6)  \   \ dx  $$

$$= \  \int_{-1}^{1}   \ ( 3x + \frac{7}{3}  - 2x^4  - 2x^3 - x^5  - \frac{1}{3}x^6)  \   \ dx \ =   \ \frac{14}{3}    - \frac{4}{5}     - \frac{2}{21}   \ = \ \frac{396}{105}  =  \frac{132}{35} \ ,$$

again removing the odd functions in $x$.

And the third integral is

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{y^2}^{1}   \ x^2 + 2xy + y^2  \ \ dx \ dy   \ = \  \int_{-1}^{1}   \ (\frac{1}{3}x^3 + x^2y + xy^2) \ |_{y^2}^{1}  \  \ dy   $$

$$= \  \int_{-1}^{1}   \ (\frac{1}{3} + y + y^2 - \frac{1}{3}y^6 - y^5 - y^4) \ \ dy \  = \ \frac{2}{3}  + \frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{5} - \frac{2}{21} \ = \  \frac{88}{105} \ , $$

taking out the odd functions in $y$.  All the integrals are now positive (and, significantly, have even numerators, as we would expect from the symmetrical integrations), and the surface integral (which can also be read as a volume integration) yields
$ 8 - \frac{132}{35} - \frac{88}{105} \ = \ \frac{356}{105} \ \approx 3.3905.$

[So I *am* getting all of your values, though I don't know where you're getting your minus signs. (You didn't count your second and third integrals as negative and then subtract them off *again*, did you?)  This is one *weird* region and a bear of a computation...]